# Getting Context from other class causing NPE

Tags: android

I'm trying to call a new activity in non-activity class using this codes:

```
Intent usage = new Intent(UsageActivity.getContext(),UsageActivity.class);
usage.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
UsageActivity.getContext().startActivity(usage);
```

and I have a UsageActivity that has this codes:

```
public static Context mContext;
```

below the onCreate()

```
mContext = getBaseContext();
```

I created a method like this:

```
public static Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }
```

It throws an exception saying this:

> 08-23 12:51:39.439: E/AndroidRuntime(15059): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       08-23 12:51:39.439: E/AndroidRuntime(15059): java.lang.NullPointerException
>       08-23 12:51:39.439: E/AndroidRuntime(15059):    at android.content.ComponentName.(ComponentName.java:75)
>       08-23 12:51:39.439: E/AndroidRuntime(15059):    at android.content.Intent.(Intent.java:3301)
>       08-23 12:51:39.439: E/AndroidRuntime(15059):    at ph.teligent.nce.more.MoreManager.loadShowUsageView(MoreManager.java:673)
>       08-23 12:51:39.439: E/AndroidRuntime(15059):    at ph.teligent.nce.more.MoreView.onItemClick(MoreView.java:125)
>       08-23 12:51:39.439: E/AndroidRuntime(15059):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
>       08-23 12:51:39.439: E/AndroidRuntime(15059):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1086)
>       08-23 12:51:39.439: E/AndroidRuntime(15059):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2859)
>       08-23 12:51:39.439: E/AndroidRuntime(15059):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3533)
>       08-23 12:51:39.439: E/AndroidRuntime(15059):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>       08-23 12:51:39.439: E/AndroidRuntime(15059):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>       08-23 12:51:39.439: E/AndroidRuntime(15059):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>       08-23 12:51:39.439: E/AndroidRuntime(15059):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>       08-23 12:51:39.439: E/AndroidRuntime(15059):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       08-23 12:51:39.439: E/AndroidRuntime(15059):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>       08-23 12:51:39.439: E/AndroidRuntime(15059):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>       08-23 12:51:39.439: E/AndroidRuntime(15059):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>       08-23 12:51:39.439: E/AndroidRuntime(15059):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Does my way of creating a context was wrong?
any thoghts will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to do that ( i, start activity from ) inside `AsyncTask` ?

Comment: No I'm not. The codes above are exactly what I used.

Comment: I asked because the error seems to be at `com.itaxeeta.server.Search.onPostExecute` at line 219 in Search.java class . `onPostExecute` tell me that something might be wrong in the `AsyncTask`. Nevertheless thanks for the comment. What is that line by the way ?

Comment: oh sorry that part was not showing anymore I edited my logcat error posted above.

Comment: Is it complete LogCat ?

Comment: I pasted the complete logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does my way of creating a context was wrong?

Yes you are using a context which is never existing yet and **getting the BaseContext is not a clean way** :

```
 Intent usage = new Intent(UsageActivity.getContext(),UsageActivity.class);
```

so you should pass your first Activity context which call your not-Activity class to your not-Activity class then use that context for starting the Second Activity.

```
 Intent usage = new Intent(context,UsageActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code

```
Intent i = new Intent(UsageActivity.getContext(),YourActivity.class);
            UsageActivity.getContext().startActivity(i);
```

mContext is your activity context

Also update your code in main activity with below in onCreate() from

```
mContext = getBaseContext();

to 
mContext = UsageActivity.this;
```

Comment: I already edited my codes as what you said but I still get the same error. I pasted the complete logcat above.

Comment: before sending above code i tried it on my system, it worked fine. So above way of using context is corect. We need to identify what else is causing the problem. Is your non activity class a adapter, and from where you calling Intent i mean on some event. Also share some more code

Answer (score 0):

You can't "call a new activity in non-activity class using this codes"!

You must call startActivity() in CURRENT context. You can translate the current context to the non-activity class as class field.

Answer (score 0):

It looks here

```
Intent usage = new Intent(UsageActivity.getContext(),UsageActivity.class);
```

like you are using the same activity for both arguments...can you pass context in to this activity in its constructor?

Answer (score 0):

**you are not on wrong track but you getting getBaseContext() null. Just edit one line and it will work.**

*write this line in onCreate() method of your activity.*

```
mContext = this;
```

Comment: I already edited my codes as what you said but I still get the same error. I pasted the complete logcat above.